# How can i use a record i found in database to perform other operations

Tags: vba

I was searching for a record in my database and now that the record is found
I want to know how can I use it
for example
if i want to use the name field of the record to put in text

```
If rsQ.RecordCount <> 0 Then
     ' Found it
    blnExists = True
    NameTxt.Value = Name.Value
Else
MsgBox "not found"
End If
```

It gives me an Invalid qualifier  at this line

```
 NameTxt.Value = Name.Value
```

Comment: You've asked where there are any records, but you haven't told it to retrieve one. I don't know how you do that in vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say VBA but not which database you are using. From the above, it looks like you would be better off with [DLookUp](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786) in Access. Otherwise, you can say:

```
MyVar = rsQ.Fields("[Name]")
```

Or

```
MyVar = rsQ.Fields(3)
```

BTW Name is a reserved word and should not be used.

Comment: The rsQ.Field didnt work but the DLookUp did The job Thank you